Generalized momentum
I am studying Hamiltonian Mechanics and I was questioning about some laws of conservation:
in an isolate system, the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}(q,\dot q)$ is a function of the generalized coordinates and their velocities (since the system is isolate, the Lagragian cannot depend explicitly on time due to the homogeneity of time). We define the "generalized momenta" as $p_i=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot q_i}, i=1,..,n$.
We know that if the $q_i$'s are the cartesian coordinates, then the total impulse $P=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial v_i}$ (where $v_i=( \dot x_i, \dot y_i, \dot z_i)$) is conserved.
My question is: if the generalized coordinates are not the cartesian ones, then is it true that the generalized total impulse $P=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot q_i}$ is conserved?

Generalized momentum $p^i$ is conserved if the Lagrangian function $\mathscr{L}$ doesn't depend on the generalized coordinate $q^i$. It's readily proved from the Lagrange equation,
$$\frac{d}{dt} \underbrace{ \left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{q}^i}  \right)}_{p^i} - \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial q^i} = 0 \ ,$$
that $\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial q^i} = 0$ implies $\frac{d{p}^i}{dt} = 0$.

Then the total momentum (the sum of the generalized momenta) is conserved if and only if the Lagrangian does not depend on the generalized coordinates ?

In general, you can't sum the conjugated momenta $p^i$ since they may have difference physical dimensions. As an example, using polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ the conjugated momenta have physical dimensions $[p^r] = \frac{[E] [t]}{[L]} $,  $[p^{\theta}] = {[E] [t]} $.

The total momentum  $P=\sum \partial L/\partial x_i$ in flat Euclidean space in Cartesian coordinates is conserved, if the Lagrangian $L=T-V(x_1,x_2,\dots x_n)=T-V'(R,x_1-x_2,\dots ),$ rewritten in the center of mass system, does not depend on its canonical conjugate coordinate, the center of gravity $R_s = \sum_i m_i x_i/\sum_i m_i$.
This is generally the case if all forces cancel, e.g. for a sum of inner pair potentials.
Introducing generalized coordinates for such a problem, will always introduce the coordinate of the center of gravity $R$, such that its conjugate total momentum $P$ is conserved and can be set to zero.
The generalized coordinates introduced for the description of the relative system at rest, mostly a set radius and angles, have different metric dimensions and so their conjugate momenta values do not add.
By Noether's theorem, any function of the observable is conserved, if the form is algebraically invariant with respect to a continuous symmetry of the system, translations and rotations e.g., that is, the Hamiltonian is invariant w.r.t. such a transformation.
For a generalized momentum variable, this is true obviously if the Hamiltonian does not depend on its conjugate coordinate.
In order to find conserved linear combinations of momentum variables, one has to combine them with scaling factors, mostly coordinate dependent as e.g. in the Hamiltonian of a 2-particle central force problem.
$$H = \frac{ p_1^2}{2 m_1} + \frac{p_2}{2m_2}+ V(x_1-x_2) =  \frac{P}{2 M} +  \frac{ p^2}{2\mu} +  V(x) = \frac{P}{2 M}+ \frac{1}{2M}\left( p_r^2 + \frac{L^2}{r^2}\right) + V(r).$$
This Hamiltonian is invariant with respect to translations in $R$ and rotations around the center of gravity R. The absence of $R$ and the azimuthal angle $\phi$ in the Hamiltonian yields the constancy of the translation momentum $P$  and the angular momentum $L_z$ conjugate to $\phi$.
The constancy of any other angular momentum component and the square of the vector $L^2$ is evident by symmetry, but hard to prove algebraically via equations of motion.
